# Access Method of Parent Object From ForEach Loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I think this is more of a javascript question than an angular question, but context was angular, so keeping it there. Basically I am trying to call the `doSomething` method. It looks like lodash's `._forEach` is creating its own scope, so I can't access `var service` using `this`, because that refers to the loop here.

So, what's the best way for me to call `doSomething` from where it is in the code below (inside the `forEach`)?

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').service('fooService', function()
{

    var service = {
        barMethod: function(arrayOfObjects){
            //this.doSomething(); - this works if not commented out, 
            //but I need it from within loop
            _.forEach(arrayOfObjects, function (ob) {
                this.doSomething();
            });

        },

        doSomething: function(){
            //do something
        },

    };

    return service;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
var service = {
    barMethod: function(arrayOfObjects){
          var self = this
        _.forEach(arrayOfObjects, function (ob) {
            self.doSomething();
        });

    },

    doSomething: function(){
        //do something
    },

};
```

Comment: Upvoted because I know that works without trying it, but wondering if there is some other way. I will accept answer later if not. Ty. (edit: And I confirmed that it works)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback maybe it helps you find answer

Comment: Couldn't you use an arrow function then the self hack would not be needed. `_.forEach(arrayOfObjects, ob => {this.doSomething();})`.